Create dataframe rows without individually specifying every column value?
Note: The only post about this that I could find on theses forums was about SQL INSERT statements and not about Python DataFrames.

Background:
I have a dataframe with many columns. Exactly how many isn't really important to the question. Suffice to say it is a number large enough that writing out the individual columns one at a time (or even copying them and specifying each one) is not feasible.
I want to create a second dataframe with the same columns (same number of columns, same column labels) but only populate a sparse subset of the fields of the new dataframe (this is a fraction of the total number of columns in the original dataframe). I want to put a default value (perhaps 0) in every other field in my new record.
Here's a small example. I know that the example could be brute-force solved by manually specifying the column names. As I pointed out earlier, it's not feasible in my case to write out every field name of the new row.
Original DF:
|Field1|Field2|Field3|...|Field101|Field102|Field103|
|DATA1-|------|Data3-|---|--------|Data102-|--------|
|DATA1-|Data2-|Data3-|---|--------|Data102-|Data103-|
|------|Data2-|------|---|Data101-|--------|--------|
...
and many more rows

Proposed input would be something along the lines of the following (I can use other python constructs if necessary):
{Field4: 'Hello', Field12: 'World!', Field29: 'Stack', Field61: 'Overflow', Field73: '2024', Field97: 'helps.'}

The goal is that in a new dataframe (with the same columns as the original) only those six fields are populated and everything else gets the default input (0, 'No data', whatever).
How can this be done? Some sort of list/dictionary comprehension coupled with an append (or iloc) command? Is there a simple pandas function that will do this quickly, easily, and simply?

I dont understand. You want to keep the row count of the original df? Cant you use copy and iterate over .columns?

Not sure how I i was unclear, but I'll try to address your comment. I want to leave the original data (although, if necessary not the original DATAFRAME) alone. In the end I want a NEW df with the SAME columns as the original but with my new data in it. Doesn't really matter if i append to the old one or not because i know i can just split rows off later. I was really hoping that there was something like a simple pd.insert({...}, default = '0') command that doesn't require me to specify any fields other than the ones i want to populate.

Assuming this initial dataframe from OP:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Field1": ["DATA1-", "DATA1-", "------"],
        "Field2": ["------", "Data2-", "Data2-"],
        "Field3": ["Data3-", "Data3-", "------"],
        "Field101": ["--------", "--------", "Data101-"],
        "Field102": ["Data102-", "Data102-", "--------"],
        "Field103": ["--------", "Data103-", "--------"],
    }
)

   Field1  Field2  Field3  Field101  Field102  Field103
0  DATA1-  ------  Data3-  --------  Data102-  --------
1  DATA1-  Data2-  Data3-  --------  Data102-  Data103-
2  ------  Data2-  ------  Data101-  --------  --------

You can structure your data as a dict of str to list, use this to create a new dataframe, then concatenate the original and the new dataframes:
data_dict = {
    "Field1": ["Hello"],
    "Field2": ["World!"],
    "Field3": ["Stack"],
    "Field101": ["Overflow"],
}

new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data_dict)])

   Field1  Field2  Field3  Field101  Field102  Field103
0  DATA1-  ------  Data3-  --------  Data102-  --------
1  DATA1-  Data2-  Data3-  --------  Data102-  Data103-
2  ------  Data2-  ------  Data101-  --------  --------
0   Hello  World!   Stack  Overflow       NaN       NaN

Non-exitant values will be filled with NaN. You can replace them using fillna:
new_df = new_df.fillna(0)

   Field1  Field2  Field3  Field101  Field102  Field103
0  DATA1-  ------  Data3-  --------  Data102-  --------
1  DATA1-  Data2-  Data3-  --------  Data102-  Data103-
2  ------  Data2-  ------  Data101-  --------  --------
0   Hello  World!   Stack  Overflow         0         0

